# how to get wp_editor to save data in plugin admin page

Tags: settings-api, wp-editor

I'm trying to use plugin settings api to add wp_editor, but the text is not saving.

```
// add the admin settings and such
add_action('admin_init', 'my_plugin_admin_init');
function my_plugin_admin_init(){
register_setting( 'my_plugin_settings', 'my_plugin_settings', 'my_plugin_settings_validate');
add_settings_field('my_plugin_user_custom_text', __('Enter your message','WP-Shabbat'), 'my_plugin_user_custom_text', 'my_plugin', 'my_plugin_main');

function my_plugin_user_custom_text() {
$options = get_option('my_plugin_settings');
$settings  = array('media_buttons' => false,'textarea_rows' => 5,'textarea_name' => 'user_cutom _text_msg');
wp_editor( $options['user_custom_text'],'user_custom_text', $settings  );}  

// validate  
function my_plugin_settings_validate() {
$options = get_option('my_plugin_settings');
$user_custom_text = $input['user_custom_text'];

if ( empty($user_custom_text) ){
$options['user_custom_text'] = $user_custom_text;
}else{
$options['user_custom_text'] =  __('Enter your own text','WP-my-plugin');// as set when the plugin activated
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I used the **$input**['user_custom_text'];

all I needed was **$_POST**['user_custom_text'];

also to get the media to work need wordpress Sanitize:

```
<?php wp_kses_post( $data ); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses_post